# Using RelaxNG how can I allow any element to have an attribute "myattribute" - that is define global attributes

Tags: xml, relaxng

Is there a way to declare an attribute globally available i my grammar?

That is, I want any element to be able to have a certain attribute.

Alternatively I would like to define a list of elements that can have the "id" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

A sample solution to your problem :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
    datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
    <start>
        <ref name="testDef"/>
    </start>
    <define name="testDef">
        <element name="test">
            <ref name="commonAttributes"/>
        </element>
    </define>
    <define name="commonAttributes">
        <attribute name="id">
            <data type="ID"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="otherCommonAttr">
            <data type="string"/>
        </attribute>
    </define>
</grammar>
```

You have to declare a reference to the definition of common attributes in each element, like in the element `test` in the example above.